# Importing custom object field is not working as expected in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

**object:Guest master**
**field:Guest First Name**
imported custom field as below.

**import FIRSTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Guest_Master__c.Guest_First_Name__c';**

assigned the firstname in javascript file as below

**@track GuestMasterRecord={
guestfname:FIRSTNAME_FIELD
}**

value is coming from HTML field (firstname)  to the field **guestfname**. However it is not storing in the object field First Name in the salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

The imported value is used with [getFieldValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_get_field_value) and [getFieldDisplayValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_get_field_display_value), and causes a "reference" to be created, which can be queried by [MetadataComponentDependency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm) queries to find where a field is used.

To use the token yourself, you can do something like this:

```
guestMasterRecord = {};
setFieldValue(record, field, value) {
  record[field.fieldApiName] = value;
}
handleInputChange(event) {
  setFieldValue(this.guestMasterRecord, FIRSTNAME_FIELD, event.target.value);
}
```